# JedisConnectionException Read Time Out

Tags: java, redis, timeout, jedis

I am using jedis in my Java program.Its version is **2.9.0**.

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
```

To avoid taking too much time query result by command `keys(*)`, I store keys in a set, and when need all keys, query them from set using:

```
public Set<String> getKeysFromDailySet(String day) {
    Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
    Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>();
    try {
        keys = jedis.smembers(day);
        jedis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("fail get keys from daily set {}", day);
    }
    return keys;
}
```

There's about **8 million** keys in set, and it throws Below timeout exception:

```
  Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
            at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:202) ~[scoring-20180118.jar:na]
            at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:40) ~[scoring-20180118.jar:na]
            at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:151) ~[scoring-20180118.jar:na]
            at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:215) ~[scoring-20180118.jar:na]
            at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:340) ~[scoring-20180118.jar:na]
            at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getStatusCodeReply(Connection.java:239) ~[scoring-20180118.jar:na]
            at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.select(BinaryJedis.java:523) ~[scoring-20180118.jar:na]
            at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:111) ~[scoring-20180118.jar:na]
            at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:868) ~[scoring-20180118.jar:na]
            at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435) ~[scoring-20180118.jar:na]
            at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363) ~[scoring-20180118.jar:na]
            at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:49) ~[scoring-20180118.jar:na]
            ... 9 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
            at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
            at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
            at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
            at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:108) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
            at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:196) ~[scoring-20180118.jar:na]
```

Here's my JedisPool Configuration:

```
private final int HOUR_IN_SECONDS = 3600 * 10;  // 10 HOURS
private final Configuration config;
private final int INDEX;

public DatabaseConnection(String host, Configuration config) {
    this.config = config;
    this.INDEX = config.getRedisDbIndex();
    jedisPool = new JedisPool(buildJedisPoolConfiguration(), host, 6379, HOUR_IN_SECONDS, null, INDEX);
}

private JedisPoolConfig buildJedisPoolConfiguration() {
    JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
    jedisPoolConfig.setMaxTotal(this.config.getNumberOfThreads());
    return jedisPoolConfig;
}
```

I have set timeout to 10 hours but the error occurs in 1 hour. I have read Jedis from github but didn't find samples for my case. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JedisPool` takes timeout as milliseconds. So your given timeout is actually 36 seconds, not 10 hours.

On a further note, instead of running `SMEMBERS` on a set of 8 million members, you should consider using `SSCAN` with smaller batch size.

Comment: Thanks! I have checked `SSCAN` it works great!  My bad, take milliseconds as seconds, it's hard to find jedis docs...